# Tuning JVM parameters to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, jvm, permgen, java-memory-leaks

I'm getting an error "**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space**" very often (1-2 times per week) and I cannot localize the problem.

Thread dump shows no blocked processes. And a heap dump cannot be done when this error occurs (even when parameter **Heap dump on OOME: enabled**).
I've tried many options when restart the JVM but nothing helps.
Maybe somebody knows what can be a problem seeing this screenshots from Java VisualVM?

**Tomcat 6, Java 1.6.**

**Overview JVM parameters:**
[image]

**Monitor:**
[image]

**Monitor (PermGen):**[image]

Comment: do you often redeploy your applications? This is one of the problems that used to  cause this error. I strongly recommend to switch/migrate to Java 8 if possible

Comment: The problem might be connected to class loader leakage. But is it really worth investigating problems regarding running an ancient Tomcat version on an ancient JVM, just to learn that these problems might be already known and even fixed years ago? You could save that time by just updating…

Comment: We have no access to the code. That's why we cannot change Java and tomcat versions (we tried but application not started). So every time we restart the tomcat. At last time it happens more and more frequently. Last changes in the application: we have added more users and more cron tasks. So I think: maybe threads can be the cause of this?

Comment: If the application is not yours, update Java, Tomcat *and* the application. If there is no update for the application and you haven’t the source code, you’re riding a dead horse. What does it help to find out the cause of the problem, when you can’t fix it anyway?

Comment: You are using Java1.6 which is pretty old, and getting OOM for PermGen. In Java 8 PermGen is completly replaced by Metaspace and advantage is thet you don't hit OOM in metaspace as it grows and consumes your available native memory. Best solution is to upgrade your java to use latest version